# How to change woo-commerce product detail page url

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change or edit woo-commerce single product page default URL. I want to custom URL for single product page. I want to show " category>subcategory>product name "

Also want to change breadcrumb on product detail page.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be easy - I am not sure if I understood you correctly.

In Settings>Permalinks at the very bottom you can choose structure of your shop URL.

[image]